# Python how to start reading file after a specific line to a specific line?

Tags: python

I need to make my python code reads emma.txt file after line 32 to line 16266.

```
fin = open("emma.txt", encoding="UTF-8")

fin.readline()

line= fin.readline()

word = line.strip()

print(word)

fin.close()

fin = open("emma.txt", encoding="UTF-8")

for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    print(word)
```

The problem is solved with the code below

```
emma = open("emma.txt", encoding="UTF-8")

lines = emma.readlines()[31:16265]
for line in lines:
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: do you know how to keep track of the line number?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("test.py", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

lines = lines[31:16265]
print(lines)
```

This saves all the lines as a list and then makes the list the 31st index (32nd line) to the 16265th index (16266th line).

My mistake, my previous answer was incorrect. I have changed it to
`lines = lines[21:12265]`

Comment: It's not a good idea to store all lines in memory.

Comment: This would make `lines` everything from lines 0 to 31 and then 16265 to end.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `lines = lines[31:16265]`?

Comment: I get "[]" as an output

Comment: How can I make this code reads the file without white spaces?

Answer (score 1):

Since storing all lines into memory is not a good idea. you can use `islice` from `itertools` module which gives you ability to pick which items you want from an iterator. [click](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
from itertools import islice

with open('your_file.txt') as f:
    for line in islice(f, 31, 16266):
        # do what you wanna do
```

It is much more efficient and clean.

Comment: At first glance I thought that function was called "is lice".

Answer (score 0):

Use this to get your answer fast and efficient

```
start = 31
end = 16266
with open("test.py", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()[start:end]
print(lines)
```

Comment: reads the whole file in to memory first, which can blow up memory if it is large, not an ideal approach

Answer (score 0):

```
def read_range_lines(filename, start, end):
    if end > start:
        return

    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        count = 0

        while count < start - 1:
            file.readline()
            count += 1

        while count < end:
            print(file.readline())
            count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using enumerate to track line numbers.

```
with open('f3.txt') as f:
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        if 31 <= line_no <= 16265:           # assuming line numbered from 0  
           # Processing of desired lines
            print(line)
       elif line_no > 1626i5:
           # Not required but avoids futher unnecessary file reading
           break
```